# Construct a System.Char which would have a Boolean System.TypeCode

Tags: c#, enums, char

How is it possible to construct a `System.Char` which would have a Boolean `System.TypeCode`?

The code below:

```
char c = 'f';
System.TypeCode a = c.GetTypeCode();
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

produces the following output:

```
Char
```

Now I checked the decompiled version of the `System.TypeCode`. Here it is:

```
#region Assembly System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
// System.Runtime.dll
#endregion

namespace System
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the type of an object.
    public enum TypeCode
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     A null reference.
        Empty = 0,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     A general type representing any reference or value type not explicitly represented
        //     by another TypeCode.
        Object = 1,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     A database null (column) value.
        DBNull = 2,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     A simple type representing Boolean values of true or false.
        Boolean = 3,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     An integral type representing unsigned 16-bit integers with values between 0
        //     and 65535. The set of possible values for the System.TypeCode.Char type corresponds
        //     to the Unicode character set.
        Char = 4,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     An integral type representing signed 8-bit integers with values between -128
        //     and 127.
        SByte = 5,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     An integral type representing unsigned 8-bit integers with values between 0 and
        //     255.
        Byte = 6,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     An integral type representing signed 16-bit integers with values between -32768
        //     and 32767.
        Int16 = 7,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     An integral type representing unsigned 16-bit integers with values between 0
        //     and 65535.
        UInt16 = 8,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     An integral type representing signed 32-bit integers with values between -2147483648
        //     and 2147483647.
        Int32 = 9,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     An integral type representing unsigned 32-bit integers with values between 0
        //     and 4294967295.
        UInt32 = 10,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     An integral type representing signed 64-bit integers with values between -9223372036854775808
        //     and 9223372036854775807.
        Int64 = 11,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     An integral type representing unsigned 64-bit integers with values between 0
        //     and 18446744073709551615.
        UInt64 = 12,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     A floating point type representing values ranging from approximately 1.5 x 10
        //     -45 to 3.4 x 10 38 with a precision of 7 digits.
        Single = 13,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     A floating point type representing values ranging from approximately 5.0 x 10
        //     -324 to 1.7 x 10 308 with a precision of 15-16 digits.
        Double = 14,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     A simple type representing values ranging from 1.0 x 10 -28 to approximately
        //     7.9 x 10 28 with 28-29 significant digits.
        Decimal = 15,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     A type representing a date and time value.
        DateTime = 16,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     A sealed class type representing Unicode character strings.
        String = 18
    }
}
```

And I got curious how could I make the `c.GetTypeCode()` return the `Boolean` instead of `Char`.

I tried this:

```
char c = true;
System.TypeCode a = c.GetTypeCode();
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

But that produces a compile-time error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'char' [Console.NET]csharp(CS0029)

The question is asked just out of curiosity. At least as of right now I do not have a real case where I would need this.

Comment: Well, `GetTypeCode` returns a type of object. If object has `char` type, it isn't possible to return a different type here, because it's violation of static typing

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, that raises yet another question. What is the difference between the `GetTypeCode` and the `GetType` then? Why would we need the `GetTypeCode`?

Comment: [`GetTypeCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iconvertible.gettypecode?view=netframework-4.8#System_IConvertible_GetTypeCode) is declared in `IConvertible` interface, every type implementing this interface, must implement this method. Basically, it's used to convert value to the different type, [`GetType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype?view=netframework-4.8) is declared and implemented in `System.Object` class, every object should be able to return its  type

Comment: remarks section of [`System.TypeCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.typecode?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) enum gives you short explanation, why it's needed and what is relationship between `System.Type`